# How to identify an observation exists once in a column without using duplicated() or unique()?

Tags: r, duplicates

In general, I am interested in the order in which observations use different services. Particularly, I am interested in identifying any observations (by Id) that occur once in the dataset so that I can identify those observations that have only used a service once. Eventually I would like to identify observations that have only used services twice.  In the dataset provided, there is one observation (Id=3370) that has only used services once, and one observation (Id=3360) that has used it only twice.

I have tried duplicated() and unique()

```
df=data.frame(Id=c(6431,6431,6431,6431,3066,3066,
                   3066,3371,3371,3371,3370,3360,3360),
            Order=c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2),
            Service=c("Coaching","Events","Fairs","Coaching",
                       "Coaching","Events","Fairs","Coaching",
                       "Events","Fairs","Coaching","Events","Coaching"))

> df
     Id Order  Service
1  6431     1 Coaching
2  6431     2   Events
3  6431     3    Fairs
4  6431     4 Coaching
5  3066     3 Coaching
6  3066     2   Events
7  3066     1    Fairs
8  3371     2 Coaching
9  3371     1   Events
10 3371     3    Fairs
11 3370     1 Coaching
12 3360     1   Events
13 3360     2 Coaching
```

When I run the `!duplicated()`, it does not identify what I expect ID= 3370 as this is the only observation that has a unique ID.

```
!duplicated(df$Id)
> !duplicated(df$Id)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Therefore, what code would identify that an observation only shows up once in this dataset? How can I expand this to when an observation shows up twice?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Did one of these answers help? It's good to ask follow-up questions if you have any, and then to mark the answer that helped you as accepted so that others can find it in the future (and to encourage those who took the time to answer).

Comment: @JilberUrbina In the end, I would like something as follows: 
      df=data.frame(Id=c(6431,6431,6431,6431,3066,3066,
                   3066,3371,3371,3371,3370,3370,3360,3360,3360),
            Order=c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2,3),
            Service=c("Coaching","Events","Fairs","Coaching",
                       "Coaching","Events","Fairs","Coaching",
                       "Events","Fairs","Coaching","Stop","Events","Coaching", "Stop"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't just want to know about unique `Id`, but also the counts. You could use `add_count` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Id = c(6431, 6431, 6431, 6431, 3066, 3066, 3066, 3371, 3371, 3371, 3370, 3360, 3360), Order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2), Service = c("Coaching", "Events", "Fairs", "Coaching", "Coaching", "Events", "Fairs", "Coaching", "Events", "Fairs", "Coaching", "Events", "Coaching"))  
df %>%
  add_count(Id)
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#>       Id Order Service      n
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <int>
#>  1  6431     1 Coaching     4
#>  2  6431     2 Events       4
#>  3  6431     3 Fairs        4
#>  4  6431     4 Coaching     4
#>  5  3066     3 Coaching     3
#>  6  3066     2 Events       3
#>  7  3066     1 Fairs        3
#>  8  3371     2 Coaching     3
#>  9  3371     1 Events       3
#> 10  3371     3 Fairs        3
#> 11  3370     1 Coaching     1
#> 12  3360     1 Events       2
#> 13  3360     2 Coaching     2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: TIL about `add_count`. Thanks!

Comment: I think this will work. Given n=1, I would like to create a new row where the service is "Stop". For example:            
  df=data.frame(Id=c(6431,6431,6431,6431,3066,3066, 3066,3371,3371,3371,3370,3370,3360,3360,3360), Order=c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2,3), Service=c("Coaching","Events","Fairs","Coaching", "Coaching","Events","Fairs","Coaching", "Events","Fairs","Coaching","Stop","Events","Coaching", "Stop"))

Answer (score 1):

looking for `table`?

```
> table(df$Id)

3066 3360 3370 3371 6431 
   3    2    1    3    4
```

you can add this result to your existing data.frame by using `ave`

```
> df$n <- with(df, ave(Id, Id, FUN=length))
> df
     Id Order  Service n
1  6431     1 Coaching 4
2  6431     2   Events 4
3  6431     3    Fairs 4
4  6431     4 Coaching 4
5  3066     3 Coaching 3
6  3066     2   Events 3
7  3066     1    Fairs 3
8  3371     2 Coaching 3
9  3371     1   Events 3
10 3371     3    Fairs 3
11 3370     1 Coaching 1
12 3360     1   Events 2
13 3360     2 Coaching 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are clearly a number of ways to do this. :) This may not be quickest, but it's intuitive:

- Group by ID
- Count observations
- Filter for singletons... or doubles, etc.
- Drop the dummy field we just made

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarise(observations = n()) %>% 
  filter(observations == 1) %>% 
  select(-observations)
```

This results in one record per *ID* whether you're checking for `observations == 1`, `observations == 2`, or `observations == whatever`. `add_count` will always return one record per *raw observation*.

P.S. If you want it as a vector, you can use `pull(Id)` as the last line instead of `select(-observations)`.

Answer (score 1):

with `library(data.table)` we can do

```
setDT(df)[, .N, Id]
#      Id N
# 1: 6431 4
# 2: 3066 3
# 3: 3371 3
# 4: 3370 1
# 5: 3360 2
```

or to add the counts as a column

```
df[, n := .N, Id]
#       Id Order  Service n
#  1: 6431     1 Coaching 4
#  2: 6431     2   Events 4
#  3: 6431     3    Fairs 4
#  4: 6431     4 Coaching 4
#  5: 3066     3 Coaching 3
#  6: 3066     2   Events 3
#  7: 3066     1    Fairs 3
#  8: 3371     2 Coaching 3
#  9: 3371     1   Events 3
# 10: 3371     3    Fairs 3
# 11: 3370     1 Coaching 1
# 12: 3360     1   Events 2
# 13: 3360     2 Coaching 2
```